Compute explicitly the principal part of $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}a_nz^n$.
Here's the question:
Let $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n$ be the Laurent expansion of $\frac{\sin(z)\cos(z)}{z^5}$ in $0<|z|<\infty$. Compute explicitly the principal part of such Laurent series, that is, $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}a_nz^n$.
This is what I've done so far:
$\sin(z)=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\frac{z^7}{7!}+...$
$\cos(z)=1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-\frac{z^6}{6!}+...$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin(z)\cos(z)}{z^5}&=\frac{1}{z^5}\left(z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\frac{z^7}{7!}+...\right)\left(1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-\frac{z^6}{6!}+...\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{z^4}-\frac{1}{3!z^2}+...\right)\left(1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+...\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{z^4}-\frac{1}{2!z^2}-\frac{1}{3!z^2}
\end{align*}
Any feedback will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

I'd say well done. You could now put the two $\frac{1}{z^2}$ together to get $-\frac{2}{3z^2}$.

I see, thank you!

For each $z\in\Bbb C$, you have$$\sin(z)\cos(z)=\frac12\sin(2z)=z-\frac23z^3+\frac2{15}z^5+\cdots,$$and therefore, if $z\ne0$,$$\frac{\sin(z)\cos(z)}{z^5}=\frac1{z^4}-\frac2{3z^2}+\frac{2z}{15}+\cdots$$So, the principal part is $\dfrac1{z^4}-\dfrac2{3z^2}$.

Oh wow, recognising that identity was smart, thank you!
